# Rspec controller test, trying to create a test for a 'processlogin' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My create user method in the users_controller.rb looks like:

```
def process_login
   is_login_valid(params[:user][:user_name], params[:user][:password])

   if logged_in?
      redirect_to root_url
   else
      @user = User.new(params[:user][:user_name]
      redirect_to :action => 'login'
end
```

What I have currently:

```
describe UsersController do
  describe "Post 'process_login'"
    it "should be successful" do
       post 'process_login'

       response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

The methods is_login_valid and logged_in? are all included in the application_controller, and are methods from a ruby class I have in my /lib folder called LoginSystem.rb

My test is failing since it isn't mocking things correctly, this is my first time doing this so hoping someone can help me out.

Error message:

```
UsersController POST 'process_login' should be successful
     Failure/Error: post 'process_login'
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `process_login'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:21
```

Comment: I updated the q, i need the test to pass.

Comment: It might help if you give the error message.

Comment: @craig updated with error msg.

Comment: Is `params[:user]` nil? I can't see that you're setting that in your test. You dereference it with `params[:user][:user_name]`, which would cause this error. It seems to me that the controller should handle this more gracefully, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aah, Thanks for the error message. I'm assuming that line 11 is `is_login_valid(params[:user][:user_name], params[:user][:password])`.

As you're not sending any params in your test post params[:user] is nil hence the nil.[] error (when the controller is looking for params[:user][:user_name]), you set params by passing them as a hash as the 2nd parameter to post in your test.

Comment: ah, so do I create a stub for this or just pass in a dummy hash? how to do this?

Comment: ok this solved the hash problem, now it seems to be redirecting to the page if the login failed, even though I have seeting logged_in? to true.

Comment: ok I had the stub after the line of 'post' but it has to be decalred b4. thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need

```
controller.stub(:logged_in?) { true }
```

Or if you want to test that the logged_in method is actually being called

```
controller.should_receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
```

The 2nd version will cause the test to fail unless the method `logged_in?` is called once and only once

You may also need the `controller.stub(:is_login_valid} { true }` as suggested by @jaydel if you're getting an error message about this method being missing as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe:

```
controller.stub(:is_login_valid} { true }
```

should get you where you want to go, if I understand correctly.